# I need some assistance using VLC (or any other software) to batch convert midis into mp3s with their respective sound banks

Tags: shell, vlc, midi, converters

I would like to use VLC (or another software, if its easier) to convert midis with their sound banks into an mp3 or wav, or something of the sort. All the sound banks have the same name (with different file extension) as its respective .mid. I have .sf2 and .dls sound banks available. I don't have a great understanding of how VLC's command system works, and I am not at all sure how I would tell VLC to use a different bank for every file. I have 1308 midis to convert, so I don't really want to do it manually... I have read over the VLC wiki and understand how to convert a file, or multiple files normally. But I can't figure out how to use a different sound bank for every one without doing it manually.

If there is a better place to post this please let me know.

Comment: This question is too vague and broad in scope for this site. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about VLC, but you can use [timidity](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/) for converting midis to wav:

```sh
for midi in *.mid; do
    name="$(basename "$midi" .mid)"
    timidity -x "soundfont $name.sf2" -Ow -o - "$midi" | lame -V 0 -q 0 - "$name.mp3"
done
```

The example code above converts all `.mid` files in the current directory to `.mp3`s using the corresponding `.sf2` soundfont.